# Using jssor slider inside joomla custom html module

Tags: slider, jssor

Has anyone tried using this in a custom html module in joomla 3.3?  Is there any reason why it wouldn't work?  Can anyone share what they found works for this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: vina jssor joomla extensions by vinagecko.com may meet your needs.

Comment: I had a look at those. the sliders are watermarked. and don't have the versatility of the larger jssor classes. was just curious if anyone knew of any resources that could point me in the right direction, at least in terms of directory structure or something.

Comment: Please post the code that you place in custom html module. And post the output code rendered to browser.

Comment: I can post the code in just a bit but mostly i was curious if the code will run off joomlas native jquery classes or if i need to upload the jssor.slider.min.js file to the root directory of the joomla installation?

Comment: any url I can access online?

Comment: @jssor I got it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
```

The reference path of 'jssor.slider.min.js' is invalid.

You will get '404 not found' error to access http://www.cyberfishmultimedia.com/jssor.slider.min.js